Finding top 50 site in 3 miles buffer using building polygons with ArcGIS Pro
I have a CSV file that contains different site information for the State of Georgia. I currently have a building polygon and an AOI and 3 miles buffer around the sites. I want to do an analysis that shows building polygons within each buffer and select the top 50 sites from it. How can I do it?

What defines 'top'? Tallest buildings? Count of buildings? Totals of their area?

Count of Buildings inside a multiple buffer

Do pairwise intersectio. Frequency on aoi_fid. Join field to aois. Sort by frequency. Take 1st fifty
